# How can I pull records from several different tables into a single view in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: inner-join, sql-server-2008-r2, create-view

I'm attempting to create a sort of 'summary' view, where values should be pulled from several different tables ([Account],[Branch],[Customer],[Employee],[Transaction],[FlaggedTrans]).

Since I can't do a slew of SELECT statements in a view, I'm trying to accomplish the task using INNER JOINs, which is where my issue lies.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
CREATE VIEW Summary
AS
    SELECT NEWID() AS Summary_Id,
    COUNT(C.Customer_Id) AS CustCount,
    COUNT(A.Account_Id) AS AcctCount,
    COUNT(T.Transaction_Id) AS TransCount,
    COUNT(B.Branch_Id) AS BranchCount,
    COUNT(E.Employee_Id) AS EmplCount,
    CAST(SUM(A.Balance) AS INT) AS BalTotal,
    COUNT(F.FlaggedTrans_Id) AS FlagCount
    FROM dbo.Account A INNER JOIN
    dbo.Customer C ON A.Customer_Id = C.Customer_Id INNER JOIN
    dbo.Employee E ON A.Employee_Id = E.Employee_Id INNER JOIN
    dbo.[Transaction] T ON A.Account_Id = T.Account_Id INNER JOIN
    dbo.FlaggedTrans F ON E.Employee_Id = F.Employee_Id CROSS JOIN
    dbo.Branch B
```

Seems logical enough, but it's causing all of the values to come back as NULL or 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by removing the CROSS JOIN, and if needed, put it in a where clause (such as WHERE My_ID IN (Select ID from Branch).

Also, you don't have to join the tables, but select them one by one as columns as another option.  Here is some pseudocode:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(thisfield) FROM Thistable) as ThisCnt,
(SELECT COUNT(thatfield) FROM Thattable) as ThatCnt,
[etc.]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, that is exactly what I needed to do, but for whatever reason I was neglecting to put (parentheses) around the subqueries, which obviously caused SSMS to throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL if you want to build your view as a slew of selects where those single selects are not related.

Answer (score 0):

i am not really sure what is wrong here, but i can suggest you to close your inner joins one by one, and run your select query, that way you can figure which inner join is causing the problem